# Print a list of "full" relative paths of all the files present in a directory and in its sub-directories

Tags: command-line, files, directory, paths

I need to print a list of "full" relative paths of all the files present in a directory and in its sub-directories. I used to do this with du and grep:

```
du -a <path_to_directory> | grep -Po '[0-9]+\t\/\K.*'
```

But du replaces part of the paths with dots if they are too long.

Which is a good alternative?

**Parsing ls is not an option**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most straightforward option would be [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find.1):

```
$ cd /usr/lib; find .
.
./libxcb-icccm.so.4.0.0
./libbz2.so.1.0.6
./libdca.so.0
./libxcb-composite.so
./libyajl.so
./libswscale.so
./libxvidcore.so.4.3
./libjasper.so.1
./libdrm_intel.so.1
...
```

It has various tests for filtering such as:

- `-type` to filter based on type (regular file `f`, directory `d`, etc.)
- `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` to set the depths to which `find` should search (not really tests as such)
- `-name` and `-path` to filter based on filename and path, supporting wildcards.
- and a lot of other tests, for permissions, ownership, times, etc.

It offers a variety of output formats, using the `-printf` option.

---

Depending on the shell and the options enabled, you can also use globbing for this purpose. For example, in `bash`:

```
$ shopt -s globstar; printf "%s\n" **
accountsservice
accountsservice/accounts-daemon
aisleriot
aisleriot/ar-cards-renderer
aisleriot/guile
aisleriot/guile/2.0
aisleriot/guile/2.0/accordion.go
aisleriot/guile/2.0/agnes.go
aisleriot/guile/2.0/aisleriot
aisleriot/guile/2.0/aisleriot/api.go
...
```

And in `zsh`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" **/*
accountsservice
accountsservice/accounts-daemon
aisleriot
aisleriot/ar-cards-renderer
aisleriot/guile
aisleriot/guile/2.0
aisleriot/guile/2.0/accordion.go
aisleriot/guile/2.0/agnes.go
aisleriot/guile/2.0/aisleriot
aisleriot/guile/2.0/aisleriot/api.go
...
```

Comment: `find /some/absolute/path -type f -printf '%P\n'` comes to mind

Comment: Nice, I could even finally get rid of directories. `find . -type f | sed -r 's/^\///g'` and `find . -type f | sed -r 's/^\.\///g'` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @kos If you want to remove the `./` check out steeldriver's suggestion instead of using `sed` - it's not recommended for the same reason parsing ls isn't. If you must use `sed`, use `-print0` and `sed -z`.

Comment: @muru Isn't `^\.` or `^\.\/` specific enough by the way?

Comment: @muru Actually I still have dots in the middle of some path, which I missed at first. So `find` is not an option. And I'm unable to run `shopt` inside a `bash` script, which probably is the expected behavior

Comment: @kos then those dots actually exist. Find doesn't truncate output.

Comment: @muru My bad you're right, it's `wimlib` that is truncating them before in the script